Remove In Nested Loops (Remove Inside Foreach)
These are my entities:
public class Permissions
{
    public string PermissionName { get; set; }
    public List<Controllers> controllers { get; set; }
}
public class Controllers
{
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public List<Actions> actions { get; set; }
}
public class Actions
{
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

I want Remove Controllers that Have DeActive actions...
    var a1 = new Actions() { ActionName = "Action1", Active = false };
    var a2 = new Actions() { ActionName = "Action2", Active = true };
    var a3 = new Actions() { ActionName = "Action3", Active = true };
    var a4 = new Actions() { ActionName = "Action4", Active = true };

    var c1 = new Controllers() { ControllerName = "Controller1", actions = new List<Actions>() { a1, a2 } };
    var c2 = new Controllers() { ControllerName = "Controller2", actions = new List<Actions>() { a3, a4 } };

    var ListOfPermision = new List<Permissions>()
    {
         new Permissions() { PermissionName = "P1", controllers = new List<Controllers>() { c1, c2 } }
    };
    //First Way:-------------------------------
    ListOfPermision.ForEach(p =>
      p.controllers.ForEach(c =>
          c.actions.ForEach(a =>
          {
              if (!a.Active)
              {
                  //Remove Controller
              }
          }
     )));
    //OR Second Way:----------------------------
    foreach (var p in ListOfPermision)
    {
        foreach (var c in p.controllers)
        {
            foreach (var a in c.actions)
            {
                if (!a.Active)
                {
                    //Remove Controller
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //----------------------------------

The following statement should delete some Controllers Because that controllers have At least one action with Active=False...
I Dont know What Is The Best way i should to do...
What if I want to delete the controller whose action count is 0?
Thank You Guys For Your Time

instead of modifying the collection you're iterating, you could just create a copy and iterate that, while removing items form the original. Anyway: how exactly do you remove the items? The code is missing in your question.

for loop from end to start may help.

instead of modifying the collection you're iterating, you could just create a copy and iterate that, while removing items form the original.
Or even simpler:
foreach (var p in ListOfPermision)
{
    p.Controllers = p.Controllers.Where(x => x.Actions.Any(y => !y.Active)).ToList();
}

this will query all the controllers where at least one Action is not Active and store the result in the p.Controllers-property.
You can also use RemoveAll on a List<T>, which expects a Predicate<T>:
p.Controllers.RemoveAll(x => x.Actions.Any(y => !y.Active));

or when you want to remove all controllers that have no Action:
p.Controllers.RemoveAll(x => !x.Actions.Any());


maybe mark that RemoveAll is not IEnumerable<T>  but List<T> method that circumvents the original issue

@IvanPetrov OPs code is about List<T> anyway, but I add that info.

maybe also add that RemoveAll isn't making a copy like the more general LINQ approach.
